# A better way to accept multiple request types in a single view method?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to expose an API to various request methods (GET, url x-www-form-urlencoded POST, and json POST):

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        n = request.args.get('n')
        t = request.args.get('t')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            n = request.json['n']
            t = request.json['t']
        else:
            n = request.form['n']
            t = request.form['t']
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1
    ...
```

The above appears too verbose. Is there a simpler or better way of writing this? Thanks.

Comment: I typically move my API methods into a separate blueprint than my web methods. This way the functionality does not clutter each other and allows for easier maintenance. I would also look at [flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Will have to look further into blueprints. For now I opted for @Miguel's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does this look better? It is a bit cleaner in my opinion, if you can accept moving the JSON POST request to a different route (which you really should do anyway).

```
def _create_file(n, t):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1
    ...

@app.route('/create')
def create_file():
    n = request.args.get('n')
    t = request.args.get('t')
    return _create_file(n, t)

@app.route('/create', methods = ['POST'])
def create_file_form():
    n = request.form.get('n')
    t = request.form.get('t')
    return _create_file(n, t)

@app.route('/api/create', methods = ['POST'])
def create_file_json():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400); # bad request
    n = request.json.get('n')
    t = request.json.get('t')
    return _create_file(n, t)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing stopping you from rewriting your code into:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_file():
    params = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        params = request.args
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            params = request.json
        else:
            params = request.form

    n = params.get('n')
    t = params.get('t')

    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't really get much better. [Content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) is not a thing that is easily done with Flask (IMHO). By default requests are only dispatched by URL and method. I don't know how much work it is to dispatch by header value.

Comment: Then you defenetly should look at [flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I will definitely *not* do that. I will rather use https://github.com/nickstenning/negotiate which has less than 150LoC.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flask-Restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) extension as suggested by others. You can then just do something like:

```
class CreateFile(Resource):
    def get(self):
       args = parser.parse_args()
       n,t = args['n'], args['t']

    def post(self, todo_id):
       # do post stuff
```

and so on...

Comment: How does this make things shorter when it comes to content negotiation?

Comment: This is just a suggestion. The OP is asking for a "simpler or better way" and not necessarily shorter.

Comment: Well, replace "shorter" with "simpler or better" then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for since you've already accepted an answer, but you can remove a lot of the verbosity by applying standard refactoring techniques.  First, a single responsibility for each function:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_file():
    n, t = get_nt_request_data()
    return process_n(n)

def get_nt_request_data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return get_nt_query_params()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            return get_nt_json()
        else:
            return get_nt_form()
    return n, t

def get_nt_query_params():
    n = request.args.get('n')
    t = request.args.get('t')
    return n, t

def get_nt_json():
    n = request.json['n']
    t = request.json['t']
    return n, t

def get_nt_form():
    n = request.form['n']
    t = request.form['t']
    return n, t

def process_n(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1
```

Now, that's certainly not shorter, but I personally think it is much clearer.  Each individual function has a clearly defined purpose and isn't cluttered.  I would personally make "n, t" into an object with two fields, but that's totally up to you and what works for your application.  Step 2: we've got some pretty obvious copy/paste there.  Let's clean it up.

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_file():
    n, t = get_nt_request_data()
    return process_n(n)

def get_nt_request_data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return get_nt_query_params()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            return get_nt_json()
        else:
            return get_nt_form()
    return n, t

def get_nt_query_params():
    return build_nt(request.args)

def get_nt_json():
    return build_nt(request.json)

def get_nt_form():
    return build_nt(request.form)

def build_nt(resource):
    return resource.get("n"), resource.get("t")

def process_n(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1
```

Now we are getting somewhere!  But if we do this for 20 different resources (assuming your different endpoints follow similar rules for the HTTP verbs), we're going to have a bunch of get_xx_request_data functions that all basically do the same thing.  Let's parameterize!

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_file():
    n, t = get_request_data(build_nt)
    return process_n(n)

def build_nt(resource):
    return resource.get("n"), resource.get("t")

def process_n(n):
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        n = 1

# in a shared module somewhere
def get_request_data(builder):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return builder(request.args)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            return builder(request.json)
        else:
            return builder(request.form)
    return n, t
```

Down to just 11 lines of code for the endpoint, and a shared function that you can reuse for others.  (I assume this is conceptually similar to what the available frameworks end up doing; I haven't had a chance to check them out.)

One last note: creating a file with a GET request is going to get you some raised eyebrows, and possibly some weird bugs depending on how much control you have over clients and intervening proxies.  A GET is supposed to be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), so clients are supposed to be able to retry them all willy-nilly without expecting any state changes on the server (and creating something is definitely a state change).  In theory, a proxy is supposed to be able to replay a GET command after a network hiccup without even telling the original client that it tried twice, but in practice that's never caused me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a idea like this:

```py
from flask import request


class RestfulService:

    __method_init_info__ = 'method is not defined yet'

    @classmethod
    def execute(cls):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return cls.get()
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            return cls.post()
        elif request.method == "PUT":
            return cls.put()
        elif request.method == "DELETE":
            return cls.delete()

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return [cls.__method_init_info__]

    @classmethod
    def post(cls):
        return [cls.__method_init_info__]

    @classmethod
    def put(cls):
        return [cls.__method_init_info__]

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls):
        return [cls.__method_init_info__]
```

How to use:

```py
class YourService(RestfulService):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        # do your jobs here
        return []


@api.route('/project', methods=["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"])
def jobs():
    res = YourService.execute()
    return res
```